# Re-execute Next.js Script with dynamic src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

#### Summary

I have a situation where my `Next.js` app needs to load a different version of a `script`, depending on what the user selects.
Is there a way to re-execute a `script` in a component when some state changes?

```
<Script
    src={`${urlThatCanChange}/library.js`}
    strategy="beforeInteractive"
/>
```

Out of the box, the script runs with whatever the value of `urlThatCanChange` is when the component renders, but it does not re-render/initialise when `urlThatCanChange` changes.

Next docs [say this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script), but I'm wondering if there is a way around it.
[image: CleanShot 2023-04-05 at 14 19 18]

#### Additional information

```js
Running `next@13.2.3`
```

Comment: Not sure if this will be relevant to NextJs, maybe you could try to rerender the component or use the useEffect hook so whenever the user changes something the url along with component also gets rerendered.

Comment: It depends on the specific use case. It might be impossible, or there might be workarounds, or there might be a solution with a different approach (without adding a script tag). Also it depends on if you can modify the loaded scripts or not.